# Symlink instead of hardlink in Perl

Tags: perl, symlink, hardlink

I have a Perl script and I know it makes hard links of files, I wish to instead make it create symlinks, could some Perl-savvy person help me how to amend my script? I only do PHP so I can read the loop logics etc. but not sure how Perl interacts with the file system.

I assume it is in the loop starting @ line 62: `foreach my $file(@to_add) {...`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON qw( decode_json );
use Data::Dumper;

my $hashkey         = 'myKey';
my $data_folder     = '/jail/glftpd/site';
my $player_folder   = '/var/mediaplayers';
my $mediaplayersurl = "myRoute";

sub filesInFolder {
    my ($path) = @_;
    my @files = ();

    if(opendir SCANDIR, $path) {
        push @files, grep !/^\./ && -f "$path/$_", readdir SCANDIR;

        closedir SCANDIR;
    }

    return @files;
}

my $json = `wget --no-check-certificate --header "keyFile: $hashkey" -q -O - $mediaplayersurl`;
die "Failed to retrieve $mediaplayersurl!", unless defined $json;

my $data = decode_json($json);

# print Dumper $data;

foreach my $player(@$data) {
    my $sync_folder   = $player_folder."/".$player->{companyName}."/".$player->{mediaPlayer};
    my $source_folder = $data_folder."/".$player->{companyName};

    print "Preparing ".$player->{companyName}."/".$player->{mediaPlayer}."\n";

    unless(-d $source_folder) {
        print STDOUT "Source folder '$source_folder' does not exist, doing nothing.\n";

        next;
    }

    unless(-d $sync_folder) {
        system("mkdir", "-p", $sync_folder);
    }

    my @existing = filesInFolder($sync_folder);
    my %existing = map {$_, => 1} @existing;

    my @videos = ();
    foreach(@{$player->{'videos'}}) {
        push @videos, $_;
    }

    my %videos = map {$_, => 1} @videos;

    my @to_add = grep {not $existing{$_}} @videos;
    my @to_del = grep {not $videos{$_}} @existing;

    foreach my $file(@to_add) {
        my $source_file = $source_folder."/".$file;
        my $target_file = $sync_folder."/".$file;

        unless(-e $source_file) {
            print STDERR "Failed to create link to '$source_file', file does not exist.\n";

            next;
        }

        if(system('ln', $source_file, $target_file) != 0) {
            print STDERR "Failed to create link from '$target_file' to '$source_file'.\n";
        }
        else {
            print "Linked '$target_file' to '$source_file'.\n";
        }
    }

    foreach my $file(@to_del) {
        my $target_file = $sync_folder."/".$file;

        if(system('rm', $target_file) != 0) {
            print STDERR "Failed to remove file link '$target_file'.\n";
        }
        else {
            print "Removed link '$target_file'.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, since you're using `system` and `ln` to create the links, it should be as easy as just adding a `-s` argument.

Comment: Just a side note: No need to shell out for `mkdir` and `rm`. There are Perl functions for that. Have a look at [`unlink`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html) and [`File::Path::make_path`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html). They give better control over error conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to shell out. Perl has a built-in to create [`symlink`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/symlink.html)s. You can replace all of this:

```
if(system('ln', $source_file, $target_file) != 0) {
    print STDERR "Failed to create link from '$target_file' to '$source_file'.\n";
}
else {
    print "Linked '$target_file' to '$source_file'.\n";
}
```

With:

```
my $link_created = symlink $src_file, $link_name or die $!;

print "symlink created ok\n" if $link_created;
```

Comment: Nice. But you can omit the `if $link_created;` part because your snippet already dies on failure.

Comment: @PerlDog yeah, I'm aware of that, it's just for illustrative purposes. Thanks though!